# problems importing tapes from netbackup 6.0 MP7

Tags: netbackup

I'm trying to import tapes using bpimport

**bpimport -create_db_info -id 0019L3**

i got through the Phase 1 import reading 10 tapes. I'm now running bpimport (Phase 2). the job is running but i don't see any activity that shows that anything is happening. is this normal? it ran for an hour and a half and i canceled the job and started back up. still the same

bpimport

**Import phase 2 started Thu Jan 24 2013 17:07:28
INF - Importing policy NetApp-Home-6-26-09, schedule Full (netapp1_1246028403), media id 0078L3, created on 06/26/2009 08:00:03.
INF - Importing by reading INDEX file information only.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, lack of activity logs is normal for an import job.

You need a lot more patience than a hour and a half. I can only guess that after this message, NetBackup reads the entire contents of image netapp1_1246028403 from the tape, byte by byte, to collect all the filenames that are contained in that image, and to add them to the NetBackup Catalog database.

If you see the read throughput of your tape drive (e.g. from OS level tools like iostat) then it is fairly easy to calculate how long does it take to read the full tape. Just divide tape capacity by throughput (2TB / 100 MB/s = 20971.52 s = about 6 hours). In my experience it could be above four hours per tape.

I don't recall I've ever seen `Importing by reading INDEX file information only` and I don't know if it signifies any optimization of the process.